Префиксы и структура образования глаголов в русском языке
ПОМОГИТЕ! Кто-то может спросить: "О чём вы?"
Но, пожалуйста, выслушайте меня...
Русский язык для меня является вторым языком (или, по крайней мере, задумывался так).
Дело в том, что, хотя я понимаю 99% русского на слух и при чтении книг, всю свою (пока что короткую) жизнь я страдал от того, что не понимал, как образуются глаголы и какие закономерности за ними стоят.
Я могу знать 50 тысяч слов или глаголов, но когда дело доходит до того, чтобы воплотить их в жизнь и действия с помощью префиксов, я начинаю путаться. Префиксы — вот настоящая головоломка! Да, те самые "всё-просто" префиксы!
1...2...3... Начали!
«лететь», «перелететь», «полететь» и «налететь»...
Вот именно здесь я теряю направление! Всё начинает кружиться...
Я пытался выучить несколько таких глаголов и использовать их на практике, но ничего не вышло. Даже смотрел видеоуроки на YouTube.
Пожалуйста, добрые люди, помогите мне! Можете порекомендовать книги/курсы/видеоуроки, где всё это разбирается глубоко и понятно, чтобы я наконец преодолел этот языковой барьер и начал бегло говорить по-русски? Это моя мечта!
Спасибо

Глубоко и понятно? Мне кажется, нужно приложить собственные усилия для этого.

За основу можно взять учебные материалы из Сети, например:

Значения приставок Образование вида глаголов
Основные приставки русского языка и их значение

Нужно работать с толковым словарем на Грамоте.ру. Приставки многозначные, например ПЕРЕ имеет 14 значений, но основным является пространственное значение 1. Обозначает направленность движения, действия через какое-л. пространство или предмет. Перейти (улицу или через улицу); перешагнуть, перебросить (через забор).

Смотрите глагол перелететь, там 4 значения, но первое основное:  1. (кого-что или через что). Летя, преодолеть какое-л. пространство, оказаться по другую сторону чего-л. П. море. П. через Альпы.
Пространственное значение приставок нужно понять прежде всего.

Пары лететь — летать

ЛЕТЕТЬ, лечу, летишь; нсв. 1. Передвигаться, перемещаться по воздуху. Птицы летят на юг. Самолёт летит в Петербург. Пыль летит в глаза.
ЛЕТАТЬ, -аю, -аешь; летающий; нсв. 1. =Лететь (1 зн.), но обозначает действие повторяющееся, совершающееся в разных направлениях. Птицы летают на юг. Тополиный пух летает в воздухе. Пули летали над нашими головами.

Надо учитывать соответствие приставок и предлогов §199. Выбор предлога

Работать с примерами удобно на сервисе Карта слов


